# How make collapse menu on bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make menu expande/collapse to left. Like this:

[image]

[image]

On bootstrap I can do that. But I need to display extra blocks in left menu. When menu is open extra block display under menu line. Like this:
[image]

[image]

In this block I need to display controls such as dropdown and inputs.

Comment: Add some html, it will be much easier to help

Comment: Yes, please provide some code snippet of what you've tried already so that we can better assist you.

Comment: I get sample from here: https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-sidebar-examples-e363021395ff#.fbfgqm4ed